# Javascript table from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, tabular

I have something like this, but bigger.

```
[{
"votes":200,
"invalid_votes":140,
"valid_votes":60,
"voting_section":{"level":2, "zone1":"US", "zone2":"Delaware"}
},
{
"votes":300,
"invalid_votes":40,
"valid_votes":260,
"voting_section":{"level":3, "zone1":"US", "zone2":"California", "zone3":"Los Angeles"}
}]
```

I am trying for hours to transform this array into a table.

My goal is to put in the first column of the table the last zones (in our case zone2 and zone3) in voting_section (for example, the first column will have 2 lines: Delaware and Los Angeles.

In the header of the table I want to put all the other properties(votes, invalid_votes, valid_votes).

The intersection will be completed with the values:

So it has to be something like this:

[image: Table]

Here I have my code so far, but I don't think I'm going in a good direction:

```
 function createTableKeyValue2(arrObjects, parentDiv) {
                var elTable = document.createElement("table");
                elTable.className = "table table-striped table-bordered";
                var elTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
                for (var i = 0; i < arrObjects.length; i++) {
                    var elTableRow = document.createElement("tr");
                    var elTableDataKey = document.createElement("td");
                    elTableDataKey.innerHTML = arrObjects[i];
                    var elTableDataValue = document.createElement("td");
                    elTableDataValue.innerHTML = arrObjects[i];
                    //elTableDataValue.id = arrObjects[i].key.split(' ').join('_');
                    elTableRow.appendChild(elTableDataKey);
                    elTableRow.appendChild(elTableDataValue);
                    elTableBody.appendChild(elTableRow);
                }
                elTable.appendChild(elTableBody);
                parentDiv.append(elTable);
            }

            var votingSection = function(zone) {

                var voting_section = [];
                var level = zone[0].voting_section.level;
                for (var i = 0; i < zone.length; i++) {
                    voting_section.push(zone[i].voting_section['zone' + level]);
                }
                return voting_section;
            };

createTableKeyValue(votingSection(zone2), resultsTableDiv);
```

resultTableDiv is a node in the DOM.

Comment: Can you show some work? What have you tried?

Comment: I have edited the question with the code

Comment: There's quite a few of these already. Here's one that I've made an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224584/adding-data-rows-dynamically-from-a-json-object-using-javascript/44224673#44224673 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648618/creating-table-like-structure-with-spanned-rows-using-css/43649959#43649959

Comment: since there is no javascript table, i'm thinking I would create a whole new array structured as you wish.  You would finally iterate that array into an HTML `table`.  keep the array as there are a [boatload of built-in array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) you can use on it.

Comment: I have some questions. When you say the first column will have two lines, do you actually mean that the second line will be another row in the table? Also you say you want last zones, please clarify. Do you want the ultimate zone for each voting_section object (as it is written)? For this rule you should state that you want the zone with the highest number appended to it.

Comment: Note that objects aren't ordered, so the concept of "last zone" must be expressed in some other way, not "last" in the object literal. So do you mean "zone with the highest number"?

Answer (score 1):

I've interpreted your question as though you want to extract 1 zone from voting_section, that zone should have the highest number appended to it.

```js
var data = [{
      "votes": 200,
      "invalid_votes": 140,
      "valid_votes": 60,
      "voting_section": {
        "level": 1,
        "zone1": "US",
        "zone2": "Delaware"
      }
    },
    {
      "votes": 300,
      "invalid_votes": 40,
      "valid_votes": 260,
      "voting_section": {
        "level": 1,
        "zone1": "US",
        "zone2": "California",
        "zone3": "Los Angeles"
      }
    }
  ],
  html = "";

function getLastZone(voting_section) {
  var highestZone = {
    zoneNumber: null,
    zoneText: null
  };
  for (var zone in voting_section) {
    var checkZone = /zone(\d)/g.exec(zone);
    if (checkZone) {
      if (parseInt(checkZone[1]) > highestZone.zoneNumber) {
        highestZone = {
          zoneNumber: [checkZone[1]],
          zoneText: voting_section[zone]
        };
      }
    }
  }
  return highestZone.zoneText;
}

data.forEach(function(e, i) {
  html += "<tr>" + "<td>" + getLastZone(e.voting_section) + "</td>" + 
                   "<td>" + e.votes + "</td>" + 
                   "<td>" + e.valid_votes + "</td>" + 
                   "<td>" + e.invalid_votes + "</td>" + "</tr>";
})

document.getElementById("putHere").innerHTML = html;
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
th, td {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Zone</th>
      <th>Votes</th>
      <th>Valid Votes</th>
      <th>Invalid Votes</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="putHere"></tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create one main function to build the table, from which you could call a row-building function (while iterating over the data rows). I've added an example to my post here.

```js
var data = [{
  "votes":200,
  "invalid_votes":140,
  "valid_votes":60,
  "voting_section":{"level":2, "zone1":"US", "zone2":"Delaware"}
},
{
  "votes":300,
  "invalid_votes":40,
  "valid_votes":260,
  "voting_section":{"level":3, "zone1":"US", "zone2":"California", "zone3":"Los Angeles"}
}];

var buildTable = function(data, container){
  /* Builds one data row into a <tr> element string */
  var buildRow = function(rowData){
    return `<tr><td>${rowData.voting_section.zone2}</td><td>${rowData.votes}</td><td>${rowData.valid_votes}</td><td>${rowData.invalid_votes}</td></tr>`;
  }
  
  /* Reduces the array of row data into one string */
  var rows = data.reduce(function(rows, row){
    return rows+buildRow(row);
  }, '');
  
  /* Creates the full table and includes the rows string */
  container.innerHTML = `<table><thead><tr><td></td><td>Votes</td><td>Valid Votes</td><td>Invalid Votes</td></tr></thead><tbody>${rows}</tbody>`;
}

var resultsTableDiv = document.getElementById('results')
buildTable(data, resultsTableDiv);
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table from it using the javascript DOM objects,

```
myArray = [{
"votes":200,
"invalid_votes":140,
"valid_votes":60,
"voting_section":{"level":2, "zone1":"US", "zone2":"Delaware"}
},
{
"votes":300,
"invalid_votes":40,
"valid_votes":260,
"voting_section":{"level":3, "zone1":"US", "zone2":"California", "zone3":"Los Angeles"}
}]

table = document.getElementById("myTable")
    //In case is is called multiple times this forces the table to be empty
while(table.rows[0] !== undefined) {
    table.deleteRow(0)
}
    //Creates the empty cell in the top left
row = table.insertRow(0)
row.insertCell(0)
pos = 0

    //Creates the column labels
for(var name in myArray[0]) {
    if (name !== "voting_section") {
        pos += 1
        cell = row.insertCell(pos)
        cell.innerHTML = name
    }
}

    //creates the row labels, by changing how the last item is selected or what it contains you can produce a different label
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(i+1)
    lastItem = myArray[i].voting_section[Object.keys(myArray[i].voting_section)[Object.keys(myArray[i].voting_section).length - 1]]
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = lastItem
}

    //creates the values
pos = 0
for(var name in myArray[0]) {

    if (name !== "voting_section"){
        pos += 1
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            row = table.rows[i+1]
            cell = row.insertCell(pos)
            cell.innerHTML = myArray[i][name]
        }
    }
}
```