# How to create a table with Javascript and/or JQuery dynamicaly from an Object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dynamic table with javascript where the values from "A" should be summed if "M" has the same value. In addition, the table header should be created from the values from "Code". I'm sorry that I can't describe it better, but I hope that my example shows what I mean.

```js
var arr = [{
  "M": "52800",
  "Code": "093",
  "A": 1
}, {
  "M": "52800",
  "Code": "050",
  "A": 2
}, {
  "M": "56301",
  "Code": "093",
  "A": 3
}, {
  "M": "57401",
  "Code": "060",
  "A": 1
}, {
  "M": "57401",
  "Code": "090",
  "A": 5
}, {
  "M": "57401",
  "Code": "093",
  "A": 3
}, {
  "M": "57401",
  "Code": "080",
  "A": 5
}];

console.log(arr);
```

The result table should look like:

| M | 093 | 050 | 060 | 090 | 080 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 52800 | 1 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 56301 | 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 57401 | 3 |  | 1 | 5 | 5 |

It is also possibe to create the table if the "Code" and "A" is nested in "CodeHead" like this?

```
    var arr = [{
        "M": "52800",
        "CodeHead": [{
            "Code": "093",
            "A": 1
        }, {
            "Code": "050",
            "A": 2
        }]

    }, {
        "M": "56301",
        "CodeHead": [{
            "Code": "093",
            "A": 3
        }]
    }, {
        "M": "57401",
        "CodeHead": [{
            "Code": "060",
            "A": 1
        }, {
            "Code": "090",
            "A": 5
        }, {
            "Code": "093",
            "A": 3
        }, {
            "Code": "080",
            "A": 5
        }]
    }];
```

Comment: What have you tried to get the desired result? I do not see any attempt(s) being made. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info

Comment: Does this help at all: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44273210/82548?

Comment: Further more the data provided doesn't match the given output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way (explanations in comments) :

```js
var arr = [{
  "M": "52800",
  "Code": "093",
  "A": 1
}, {
  "M": "52800",
  "Code": "050",
  "A": 2
}, {
  "M": "56301",
  "Code": "093",
  "A": 3
}, {
  "M": "57401",
  "Code": "060",
  "A": 1
}, {
  "M": "57401",
  "Code": "090",
  "A": 5
}, {
  "M": "57401",
  "Code": "093",
  "A": 3
}, {
  "M": "57401",
  "Code": "080",
  "A": 5
}];

//distinct M values for rows
const rows = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.M))];
//distinct Code values for columns
const cols = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.Code))];


let table = document.createElement("table");
let tableHead = document.createElement("thead");

let head = "<tr><th>M</th>";
//populate header row with values in cols array
cols.forEach(col => head += "<th>" + col + "</th>");
head += "</tr>";
tableHead.innerHTML = head;

let tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
//body will contain table rows
let body = "";
rows.forEach((row, index) => {
  //open table row and add value from rows array
  body += "<tr><td>" + row + "</td>";
  //populate row with corresponding values or empty cell
  cols.forEach(col => {
    //try to find if there is a "A" value associated with current col and row
    let value = arr.find(el => el.M === row && el.Code === col);
    let cell = value ? value.A : "";
    body += "<td>" + cell + "</td>";
  });
  body += "</tr>";
});
tableBody.innerHTML = body;

table.appendChild(tableHead);
table.appendChild(tableBody);

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect, but I have to change the data so the "Code" and "A" nested in "CodeHead". Is it also possible to create the table? I've edited my question